# como puedo cambiar el lugar donde se escribe la linea de comando

Tags: bash

Quiero cambiar el ps1 y que se vea asi

```
╔Dir: /root/
╠cmd: #aqui se escriben los comandos
╚[user1]
```

pero no sé si se puede hacer esto.. si se puede alguien ayudeme..

Answer (score 2):

Sí es posible hacer que tu terminal se vea exactamente como quieres usando [códigos de escape ANSI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI):

```
PS1='╔Dir: \w\n╠cmd: \n╚[\u]\[\e[A\e[6G\] '
```

El problema es que la parte donde va el usuario acabará siendo reemplazada por la información que los comandos o el mismo intérprete impriman en pantalla.

Por ejemplo, al ejecutar `echo foo`, así se ve mi terminal antes de ejecutar el comando:

[image: Terminal]

Y así es como se ve después de ejecutarlo (mira cómo `foo` y `╚[user]` se combinan):

[image: Terminal]

Asumo que es posible sortear este inconveniente con códigos de escape más complejos, usando `PROMPT_COMMAND` o escribiendo algún tipo de wrapper, pero mi recomendación es que mantengas la parte del comando hasta abajo para evitar problemas:

```
PS1='╔Dir: \w\n╠[\u]\n╚cmd: '
```

[image: Terminal]

Como nota adicional, también es posible colorear el prompt usando los códigos de escape mencionados anteriormente:

```
PS1='\[\e[1;34m\]╔Dir: \[\e[1;32m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\[\e[1;34m\]╠[\[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[1;34m\]]\[\e[0m\]\n\[\e[1;34m\]╚cmd:\[\e[0m\] '
```

[image: Terminal]

### Enlaces relacionados

- [Documentación oficial de Bash sobre la sintaxis aceptada por la variable `PS1`.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html)
- [Artículo de Wikipedia (en inglés) sobre los códigos de escape ANSI y algunos ejemplos básicos,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)
- [Artículo de Bash Hackers Wiki (en inglés) sobre los códigos de escape ANSI con ejemplos avanzados.](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes)

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el prompt debes usar el comando export e introducir como parámetro la variable de entorno que pretendes cambiar :

```
export PS1="Dir: \w \u cmd:“
```

Como ves, he cambiado el orden de lo que quieres en tu promt, porque, hasta donde yo sé, es imposible introducir los comandos a mitad del promt.
\w se refiere al path del directorio de trabajo actual (\W para que solo se lea el directorio, y no toda la ruta) , y \u al usuario.
De todas maneras, export cambiará el promt de manera temporal. Si quieres hacerlo definitivo, deberás incluir esa línea en tu fichero .bashrc de la siguiente manera:

```
echo 'export PS1="Dir: \w \u cmd:" ' >> ~/.bashrc'
```